# compare mysql numeric values group_concat of two columns with join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables

```
1.users

user_id     nationality    
 
  1         Egyptian     
  2         Palestinian    
  3         French
```

2. centers

```
id      center_name
 
  1         q
  12        y
  5         x
  23        z
```

3. centers_users

```
student_id      center_id
 
  1             12
  2             5
  3             5
  1             23
  2             12
```

what I expect

```
Nationality     center_name  count_of_users_from this country  
 
  Egyptian         y,z            10
  Palestinian      x,y            33
  French           x,q             7
```

I have tried many mysql queries but I cannot get the result I want

Final  query I execute:

```
 SELECT * from (SELECT (LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id))-ENGTH(REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT user_id), ',', ''))) as ss,GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT user_id) ,nationality from user where user_id in(SELECT  student_id FROM `centers_users`) GROUP by nationality)a
```

But only get the count with nationality.

When I Join with centers gives me redundancy because I cannot put "ON" condition with
group_concat

How can I implement it?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to join the tables and aggregate:

```
select u.nationality,
       group_concat(distinct c.center_name) as center_names,
       count(distinct user_id) as users_from_this_country
from users u join
     user_centers uc
     on u.user_id = uc.student_id join
     centers c
     on c.center_id = uc.center_id
group by u.nationality;
```

You may be able to use `count(*)` for `users_from_this_country`.  It depends on how you want to count a user who is in multiple centers in the same country.

Comment: Thanks sir, Brevity is the soul of wit!!
It is working!